# Cannot get SharedPreferences value from one activity to another in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preferences for saving data and accessing it from another activity. I have used suggested methods but they don't seem to work.

Code:

```
private static String Module_Pref="ModulePreference";
```

Activity A:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
```

**Activity B:**

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        tempValue= sharedPreferences.getString(Module_Pref, "empty");
```

**Activity C:**

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
```

Here if we run first time then pass through  A, set **nosave**, then if we go to activity C then **save** the data.

What is wrong with this code.I am getting a null. I looked at file explorer also where pref file isn't saved.

Answer (score 2):

use this method to create a sharedPreference and then access it with this same name from any where in any activity within the same app

```
SharedPreference sp;
sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(My_PREFERENCE,
                context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor e = sp.edit();
e.put(key,value);
e.commit();
```

and when getting the same sharedPreference in another activity use this method

```
SharedPreference sp;
sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(My_PREFERENCE,
                context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.get(key,value);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Your should use for entering data like this:

```
editor.putString(Module_Pref, "value that you want to store");
editor.commit();
```

Now For getting that String you can use this after storing the value:

```
sharedPreferences.getString(Module_Pref, "empty");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Activity A:

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString(key,value );
                editor.commit();

    Activity B:

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            tempValue= sharedPreferences.getString(key, "emptyValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sharedPreferences.getString(Module_Pref, "empty");
```

means you want to retrieve the "value" for the key- Module_Pref, if there is none, by default it will return -> "empty" .

So either,

```
editor.putString(Module_Pref, value);
```

Or

```
sharedPreferences.getString(key, "empty");
```

where "key" is same as the key in:

```
editor.putString(key, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("main",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
                ed.putString("personEmail",personEmail);
                ed.putString("personName",personName);
                ed.commit();
```

this is used for saving values in shared pref & for accessing it use ->

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("main",0);
                sp.getString("personEmail",null);
                sp.getString("personName",null);
```